# OSX shell script open new terminal window and run program

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a short shell script to open a new terminal window and launch a program. Here is what I have:

```
osascript <<END
tell application "Terminal"
    make new window
    activate
    set contents of window to "./hello" & return
end tell
END
```

> execution error: Terminal got an error: AppleEvent handler failed.
>   (-10000)

Can anyone tell me how to do this? In a perfect world, I'd also like this script to run on Linux, so if there is a method that will be portable, that would be preferable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this :

```
 osascript<<EOF
tell application "System Events"
  tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down
end
tell application "Terminal"
  activate
  do script with command "./hello" in window 1
end tell
EOF
```

Answer (score 5):

The `do script` command runs a command in a new Terminal window:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "uptime"'
```